# Power BI can't establish a one-to-one relationship, cardinality issue

Tags: powerbi, relationship

I've got an issue with establishing relationships in Power Bi that I can't seem to solve. I've got two tables, Table 1 and Table 2. Table 1 has a column "Consignment ID" and Table 2 has a column "Consignment number".

The column "Consignment ID" will have a big list of numbers and "Consignment number" will have a smaller list, all of which should match with a corresponding number in "Consignment ID". Therefore, I would like to establish a One-to-One relationship between these two columns and then use this relationship to extract the matching numbers from the "Consignment ID" column. However, Power BI is telling me that the "cardinality isn't valid for that relationship". I'm not sure why that is and I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to do that?

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Are the column data types the same? Are you sure you don't have duplicates in any of the columns? If yes, 1:1 has to work.

Comment: Oh right. I have a couple of duplicates in one columns I just realized. Does that mean I have to use a Many to Many relationship to make it work?

Comment: If you have duplicates in only Table 2 (for example), and no duplicates on Table 1, it's a Many to One relationship (Table 2 - N:1 - Table1), so that when you select a value from Table1 Consignment ID, it filters all the records in Table2 with that ID.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question and to make it a visible solution:

If you really want **1:1** relationship between Table1 and Table2, you can't have duplicates in any of the columns that are related, otherwise it is a **N:1** or **1:N** relationship.

Answer (score -1):

Do a merged query into a new table. 1:1 relationship is only useful if you can guarantee the relationship with foreign key and not null constraints and the debugging is incredibly difficult. A merged query is less rigid and you can debug any issues in your resulting data without a generic error message.

[image]